# Only create new record if the value is different in the joint table in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

It's like adding students to a classroom

Each time I upload students through CSV file they are associated with the current classroom and  the same students can be uploaded to an another classroom

```
has_many :classroom_students
has_many :students, through: :classroom_students

has_many :classroom_students
has_many :classrooms, through: :classroom_students
```

I am trying to update the students and classrooms model through a CSV file where the CSV file will have the ids of the students. I am more interested in the joint table since I am handling the student/classroom name with uniqueness: true

I have students and classrooms model and a joint table classroom_students

How to create a new record in my joint table only if the value is different and show a notice if they already present?

below is the code I am currently using to create a new record

```
 student = Student.last
 classroom = Classroom.last

 student.classrooms << classroom
```

complete code below

```
def self.import(file, user_id)
        spreadsheet = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(file.path)
        header = spreadsheet.row(1)
        (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
          row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
          student = find_by(id: row["id"]) || new
          student.attributes = row.to_hash.merge(user_id: user_id)
          student.save!

                #for creating an associating for the new students added
                student = Student.last
                classroom = Classroom.last
                student.classrooms << classroom     
        end
      end 
    end # end class
```

Comment: Can you add your models and explain this a bit better: *How to create a new record in my joint table only if the value is different and show a notice if they already present?* ... What joint table? What value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a uniqueness validation on your `ClassroomStudent` model - requiring the `student_id` to be unique, but scoping it to the `classroom_id`, will effectively mean that you're requiring that the combination of both `student_id` and `classroom_id` is unique, which I think is what you're looking for. That'd mean that more students could be joined to the same classroom, and the same student could be joined to more classrooms, but the same student couldn't be joined to the same classroom again. In `ClassroomStudent`:

```
validates :student_id, uniqueness: { scope: :classroom_id, message: "can only belong to this classroom once" }
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: This prevents me from uploading the same student to the new classroom, Also it only validates after the 1st record is created not sure why?

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using? The scope should mean that it effectively filters on classroom, so the same student and a different classroom should still work. Not sure what you mean by "only validates after the 1st record is created", it's only going to kick in when a `ClassroomStudent` with the same `student_id` and `classroom_id` already exists, and you're trying to save an additional one - that'll stop it from being created, and you can handle the validation error however you need to in order to flag that to the user who uploaded the CSV file.

Comment: I am using Rails 5.1.3, I edited the question so it does have the complete code at the end don't know where I am going wrong